# React delete answer handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to delete an answer next to the delete button I'm pressing. I'm generating a list of answers and next to each answer there is a corresponding delete button. However, when I press the Delete button the last two answers are always getting deleted. I tried using splice method as well but result is the same. Maybe there is a problem with parameters I'm passing but I'm really not sure at this point.

Edit: I figured my handlers in this part of code are being executed twice, however, I can't find the reason for that behavior:

```
{poll.questions.map((questionObj, questionIndex) => (
        <div key={questionIndex}>
          <h2>
            {questionObj.question +
              (questionObj.multiChoice
                ? " - (multiple choice)"
                : " - (single choice)")}
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => handleDeleteQuestion(questionIndex)}>
              Delete question
            </button>
          </h2>
          {questionObj.choices.map((choice, choiceIndex) => (
            <div key={choiceIndex}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Choice ${choiceIndex + 1}`}
                value={choice.text}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleAnswerChange(questionIndex, choiceIndex, e.target.value)
                }
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event propagation
              handleDeleteAnswer(questionIndex);
            }}
          >
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Entire code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function NewPoll() {
  const [poll, setPoll] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    multiChoice: false,
    questions: [],
    answers: [],
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
    const newValue = type === "checkbox" ? checked : value;

    setPoll((prevPoll) => ({
      ...prevPoll,
      [name]: newValue,
    }));
  };

  const handleMultipleAnswer = () => {
    const question = prompt("Enter the multiple-choice question:");

    if (question !== null) {
      const numAnswers = parseInt(
        prompt("Enter the number of possible answers:"),
        10
      );

      if (!isNaN(numAnswers)) {
        const newQuestion = {
          question,
          choices: Array(numAnswers).fill(""), // Initialize with empty strings
          multiChoice: true,
        };

        setPoll((prevPoll) => ({
          ...prevPoll,
          questions: [...prevPoll.questions, newQuestion],
        }));
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSingleAnswer = () => {
    const question = prompt("Enter the single choice question:");

    if (question !== null) {
      const numAnswers = parseInt(
        prompt("Enter the number of possible answers:"),
        10
      );

      if (!isNaN(numAnswers)) {
        const newQuestion = {
          question,
          choices: Array(numAnswers).fill(""), // Initialize with empty strings
          multiChoice: false,
        };

        setPoll((prevPoll) => ({
          ...prevPoll,
          questions: [...prevPoll.questions, newQuestion],
        }));
      }
    }
  };

  /*  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(poll.questions.length).fill(false)
  );
const handleChoiceChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, choiceIndex) =>
    choiceIndex === position ? !item : item
    );

    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
  };

  */

  const handleAnswerChange = (questionIndex, choiceIndex, newText) => {
    setPoll((prevPoll) => {
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevPoll.questions];
      updatedQuestions[questionIndex].choices[choiceIndex] = newText;
      return {
        ...prevPoll,
        questions: updatedQuestions,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleDeleteQuestion = (questionIndex) => {
    setPoll((prevPoll) => {
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevPoll.questions];
      const deletedQuestion = updatedQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1)[0];

      deletedQuestion.choices = [];

      return {
        ...prevPoll,
        questions: updatedQuestions,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleDeleteAnswer = (questionIndex) => {
    setPoll((prevPoll) => {
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevPoll.questions];
      const lastQuestion = updatedQuestions[questionIndex];

      if (lastQuestion.choices.length > 0) {
        lastQuestion.choices.pop(); // Remove the last choice
      }

      console.log("hey");

      return {
        ...prevPoll,
        questions: updatedQuestions,
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Enter poll name:</h1>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={poll.name}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      <h1>Enter a description:</h1>
      <textarea
        rows="10"
        cols="50"
        name="description"
        value={poll.description}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      ></textarea>{" "}
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleMultipleAnswer}>
        Create a question with multiple answers
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleSingleAnswer}>
        Create a question with a single answer
      </button>
      {poll.questions.map((questionObj, questionIndex) => (
        <div key={questionIndex}>
          <h2>
            {questionObj.question +
              (questionObj.multiChoice
                ? " - (multiple choice)"
                : " - (single choice)")}
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => handleDeleteQuestion(questionIndex)}>
              Delete question
            </button>
          </h2>
          {questionObj.choices.map((choice, choiceIndex) => (
            <div key={choiceIndex}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Choice ${choiceIndex + 1}`}
                value={choice.text}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleAnswerChange(questionIndex, choiceIndex, e.target.value)
                }
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event propagation
              handleDeleteAnswer(questionIndex);
            }}
          >
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <br />
      <button> Create a new poll </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default NewPoll;
```

This is the code I tried so far

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of how you can work around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `handleDeleteAnswer` is firing once, but your `setPoll` callback is firing twice. You can verify this by placing a `console.log` at the very start of `handleDeleteAnswer` and another at the very start of your `setPoll` callback. I believe this is due to using `React.StrictMode` in development. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856

To get around this, I would suggest assigning unique ID's to each of your questions and choices, then use these ID's to identify which item you want to delete rather than using the index. Even if the `setPoll` call fires twice, the ID you deleted the first time will no longer exists the second time - it's idempotent.

For a quick and dirty example, I've hacked about in your code and updated it so that where you initialize you're `choices` array, I now map it to an object containing an ID:

```
// choices: Array(numAnswers).fill("")
choices: Array(numAnswers).fill("").map((choice, i) => ({id: i, choice}))
```

When rendering your choices, pass in the `choice.id` into the `handleDeleteAnswer` function rather than the index of the choice.

```
{questionObj.choices.map((choice, choiceIndex) => (
  <div key={choice.id}>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder={`Choice ${choiceIndex + 1}`}
      value={choice.text}
      onChange={(e) =>
        handleAnswerChange(questionIndex, choice.id, e.target.value)
      }
    />
    <button
      onClick={() => handleDeleteAnswer(questionIndex, choice.id)}
    >
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
))}
```

And update the `handleDeleteAnswer` function to use the choiceId to locate the choice that's to be deleted:

```
const handleDeleteAnswer = (questionIndex, choiceId) => {
  setPoll((prevPoll) => {
    console.log(prevPoll);
    const updatedQuestions = [...prevPoll.questions];
    updatedQuestions[questionIndex].choices = updatedQuestions[
      questionIndex
    ].choices.filter((choice) => choice.id !== choiceId);
    return {
      ...prevPoll,
      questions: updatedQuestions,
    };
  });
};
```

As a side note, you should avoid using array indexes as element keys in situations like this; where the index is likely to change. This would be another candidate for using ID's.

Comment: This solution worked. I adjusted the code using your advice and deleting works properly. This is the thing I wanted to have firstly, a delete button next to every option but since I was using the array index multiple things were deleted. Thanks a bunch for your assistance, I really learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you have 10 boxes and 1 button to close on of the boxes or do you have 10 boxes with 10 close/delete buttons?

If you have 10 boxes and in each box you have a delete button you could use `closest`. It will look for the parent elements for a selector. Here is an example:

```
const clickHandler = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   e.target.closest("#card") // e.target.closest("[key='123']")
}

<main>
  <section id="card">
     <div id="card">
       <button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)}>
          This button will find his parent div
          as closest parent with id card
       </button>
     </div>
     <div id="card">
       <button>
         This button will find his parent div
         as closest parent with id card
       </button>
     </div>
     <div>
       <button>
         This button will find the section
         as closest parent with the id card!
       </button>
     </div>
  <section>
</main>
```

Otherwise you can also use 'event delegation'. If you ask Google for that or for closest you will find a lot of examples maybe that will help.